# IF Else with Jquery and input box

Tags: jquery

I am very very green with jquery.  I know the logic but am missing how to get this to work properly.

Basically this checks if the input box has the @ sign in it and if it does returns a message.  This is probably very simple but im lost at the moment.

```
<script>
               $("input[name='email']").keyup(function () {
                 if($("#emailaddress").val().indexOf("@")){
                    $(".dynamic").html('Do Not include @domain.net');
                 }else{
                 $(".dynamic").html(this.value + '@domain.net');
                      }
             });
             </script>
```

I also tried to make it so it just changes the background using this

```
<script>
               $("input[name='email']").keyup(function () {
                 $(".dynamic").html(this.value + '@domain.net');

                 $("input[name='email']:contains(@)").css("background-color", "yellow");
             });
             </script>
```

Neither work

Here is the part of my form i am looking at

```
    <div class="form-row">

          <div class="form-group col-md-auto ">
              <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Your Email Username Only <b>Do not include your FULL Email</b></small>
            <input type="text" class="form-control email" id="emailaddress" name="email" placeholder="Your E-mail username ONLY IE: johns" required >
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-auto ">
            <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted"><br /></small>
            <div> <span class="dynamic" style="font-size: 26px"></span>
             <span class="static" style="font-size: 26px"></span>
             <script>
               $("input[name='email']").keyup(function () {
                 if($("#emailaddress").val().indexOf("@")){
                    $(".dynamic").html('Do NOt include @domain.net')
                 }
                 $(".dynamic").html(this.value + '@domain.net') <-----This works


             });
             </script>

            </div>
          </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what is going wrong?

Comment: It does not change any information when a user inpute username@domain.com.  They should only input username without the @domain.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace condition to `$("#emailaddress").val().indexOf("@")>=0`. The indexOf() method returns the index within the calling String object of the first occurrence of the specified value, starting the search at fromIndex. Returns -1 if the value is not found.

```
$("input[name='email']").keyup(function () {
  if($("#emailaddress").val().indexOf("@")>=0){
    $(".dynamic").html('Do Not include @domain.net');
  }else{
    $(".dynamic").html(this.value + '@domain.net');
  }
});
```

See in playground: https://jsfiddle.net/denisstukalov/exw78vfp/3/#&togetherjs=Io1neFKzQu

Comment: Your answer would be better if you explained _why_ something fixed an issue, rather than just fixing the code.

Answer (score 0):

The function `indexOf()` can return a zero, indicating that the string has been found at the very beginning of the string. If the string is not found at all, it returns `-1`.  So you can *not* simply check it like

```
if( something.indexOf('foobar') ) {
   // found
}
```

Instead, if you have to check if the value is -1 like so

```
if( something.indexOf('foobar') > -1 ) {
   // found
}
```